# I have click event attached to elements <li>, but it only fires once on the first <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have click event attached to elements `<li>`, but it only fires once on the first `<li>`. I can see its child element also has click event attached. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-item").click(function(){
    console.log("I am clicked");
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="myclick nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Link A</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="myclick nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link B</a>
      </li>
      <li class="myclick nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link C</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: Clicking on all 3 `.nav-item`s results in the listener running for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav-item").get(0).click(function(){
    console.log("I am clicked");
});
try this.
```

You need to call native DOM click() method in order to trigger clicking behavior. This is a exception to ancher tag by jQuery. To get native DOM from jQuery object you can use get(0) or simply [0]. Eg: $(".nav-item").get(0) or $(".nav-item")[0]

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: You need to call native DOM click() method in order to trigger clicking behavior. This is a exception to ancher tag by jQuery. To get native DOM from jQuery object you can use get(0) or simply [0].

Eg: $(".nav-item").get(0)
or 
$(".nav-item")[0]

Comment: I have modified the default carret given by jQuery, making it bigger and different color for every <li>, and also it points downward when the pulled down menu is closed, and upward when the pulled down menu is open.

Comment: To get around it, I have the following:
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".nav-link").click(function(){
       console.log("I am clicked");
      });
    })

Going back to my question, why when I use the selector .nav-item, the first <li> only fires once, but when I use .nav-link, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Location of Javascript inside your HTML is very crucial. Looks like the click event is not properly attached with the HTML DOM elements.

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".nav-item").on("click", function(e){
     console.log("I am clicked");
   });
})
```